# How can i select values on mysql table using cookie

Tags: php, mysql

How can i select values on mysql table using cookie?

I wanted to select values on mysql table depending on a cookie.

I have this query,

```
    function db_prepare_input($string)
    {
        if (is_string($string)) {
            return trim(stripslashes($string));
        } elseif (is_array($string)) {
            reset($string);
            while (list($key, $value) = each($string)) {
                $string[$key] = tep_db_prepare_input($value);
            }
            return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
        } else {
            return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
        }
    }
    $country_id = db_prepare_input($_COOKIE['country']);

    $catglobal_sql = "select p.*, case when p.specials_new_products_price >= 0.0000 and p.expires_date > Now() and p.status != 0 then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price from " . TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS . " p INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id where MATCH (p.products_name,p.products_description) AGAINST ('%".$search_key."%') OR p.products_name like '%".$search_key."%' and s.countries_id = '".$country_id."' and p.display_product = '1' and p.products_status = '1' ".$duration." order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name";
    $catglobal_1     = mysql_query($catglobal_sql);
```

The cookie is set on `header.php` file,

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['country'])) 
{ 
 $country = strtolower($_POST['country']); 
 setcookie("country", $country, time()+604800, '/'); // cookie expires in 7 days.
}
?>
```

I call the query in `index.php`.

Say, the `$_COOKIE['country']` is set to `168`
I wanted to select values `WHERE s.countries_id = '168'`

However, the cookie output is blank.. so it becomes `WHERE s.countries_id = ''` thats why there are no values returned.

I need to find a way to use cookie on the `WHERE` clause

Comment: What happens when you run the query? Does it give an error? Pull up the wrong data?

Comment: echo $catglobal_sql; is it what you expect?

Comment: you dont run the query in the code shown above.

Comment: I have updated the code and my post.

Comment: $catglobal_1     = mysql_query($catglobal_sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: No. I have no problems with running the query.. my problem is outputting the values where s.country_id = $_COOKIE['country']. It displays nothing.

Comment: does it work if you replace $_COOKIE['country'] with a hard codded value?

Comment: I tried that.. I have updated again my post to better explain the problem.

Comment: Can you also check that $_COOKIE['country'] is set before you call `db_prepare_input`, and the value of $country_id once it's run?

Comment: sigh, so its really nothing to do with the query, mysql at all, ok ... so how do you set the cookie value ?

Comment: I have updated again my post above.

Comment: I have fixed the problem myself. Thank you Dagon.